# Zend Framework - How to implement partials which contain logic

Tags: zend-framework, partial

I have a layout which works fine. This layout contains several partials, which display adverts, a side column a slideshow, etc. All of these are likely to change depending on which page (module/controller/action) of the site you are on.

What is the best way of doing this correctly? In the past I have assigned variables to my view inside my controllers, these are then passed to the partial which then displays the correct slideshow or advert. This seems ugly and not entirely correct for an MVC application.

Does anyone have any other methods of doing this?

Comment: Do you have completely different adverts/slideshows for each action, or do you just want to be able to override a default in some cases?

Comment: The underlying HTML is the same for each slideshow/advert. But the content sent would be different, e.g. a different image url, link url. But for the side column the content could be completely differnt, e.g. for one controller it could contain a list of friends, or another controller a list of notifications and for another a log in form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials are just another view scripts.

My advice is: *newer put your logic into the view scripts*. Your may store the logic in:

- models (remember, that you can create your own models, extending, or not extending the basic database models, eg. data hydrators)
- view helpers (with parameters)
- services (dependent on models, returning models)
- combination of the above

Then use view helper or pass the ready data (model) to different partials.

Tip: Dependency injection is a good thing.

Comment: All good points. View Helpers sounds like the best best for me at the moment